# Is BDD really applicable at the UI layer?

Tags: testing, bdd

BDD is an **"outside-in"** methodology, which as I understand it, means you start with what you know.  You write your stories and scenarios, and then implement the outermost domain objects, moving "inwards" and "deliberately" discovering collaborators as you go--down through service layers, domain layers, etc.  For a collaborator that doesn't exist yet, you mock it (or "fake it") until you make it.  (I'm stealing some of these terms straight from Dan North and Kent Beck).

So, how does a UI fit into this?

Borrowing from one of North's [blog entries](http://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/), he rewrites this:

```
Given an unauthenticated user
When the user tries to navigate to the welcome page
Then they should be redirected to the login page
When the user enters a valid name in the Name field
And the user enters the corresponding password in the Password field
And the user presses the Login button
Then they should be directed to the welcome page
```

into this:

```
Given an unauthenticated user
When the user tries to access a restricted asset
Then they should be directed to a login page
When the user submits valid credentials
Then they should be redirected back to the restricted content
```

He does this to eliminate language from non-relevant domains, one of which is the UI (*"Name field", "Password field", "Login button"*).  Now the UI can change and the story (or rather, the story's *intent*) doesn't break.

So when I write the implementation for this story, do I use the UI or not?  Is it better to fire up a browser and execute "the user submits valid credentials" via a Selenium test, or to connect to the underlying implementation directly (such as an authentication service)?  BTW, I'm using [jBehave](http://jbehave.org/) as my BDD framework, but it could just as easily be Cucumber, rSpec, or a number of others.

I tend not to test UI in an automated fashion, and I'm cautious of GUI automation tools like Selenium because I think the tests (1) can be overly brittle and (2) get run where the cost of execution is the greatest.  So my inclination is to manually test the UI for aesthetics and usability and leave the business logic to lower, more easily automatible layers.  (And possibly layers less likely to change.)

But I'm open to being converted on this.  So, is BDD for UI or not?

PS. I have read all the posts on SO I could find on this topic, and none really address my question.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899731/should-your-bdd-specifications-be-separated-from-your-ui-tests) gets closest, but I'm not talking about separating the UI into a separate story; rather, I'm talking about ignoring it entirely for the purposes of BDD.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most people who use automated BDD tools use it at the UI layer. I've seen a few teams take it to the next layer down - the controller or presenter layer - because their UI changes too frequently. One team automated from the UI on their customer-facing site and from the controller on the admin site, since if something was broken they could easily fix it.

Mostly BDD is designed to help you have clear, unambiguous conversations with your stakeholders (or to help you discover the places where ambiguity still exists!) and carry the language into the code. The conversations are much more important than the tools.

If you use the language that the business use when writing your steps, and keep them at a high level as Dan suggests, they should be far less brittle and more easily maintainable. These scenarios aren't really tests; they're examples of how you're going to use the system, which you can use in conversation, and which give you tests as a nice by-product. Having the conversations around the examples is more important than the automation, whichever level you do it at.

I'd say, if your UI is stable, give automation a try, and if it doesn't work for you, either drop to a lower level or ensure you've got sufficient manual testing. If you're testing aesthetics anyway that will help (and never, ever use automation to test aesthetics!) If your UI is not stable, don't automate it - you're just adding commitment to something that you know is probably going to change, and automation in that case will make it harder.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Liz.  I've been referencing your blog and videos as well.  It's not lost on me that BDD is about communication more than anything else, which I think underscores my reticence to incorporate the GUI.  My stakeholders don't generally express stories in terms of the GUI anyway.

Comment: "Uncle" Bob Martin [tweeted](https://twitter.com/unclebobmartin/status/207282123835588608) on this topic twice over the weekend, adding fuel to the fire: "Tests are code! Like all code they need to be designed! Don't bind your tests to the UI!"

Comment: Only one HTML link per comment allowed, apparently.  [Here's](https://twitter.com/unclebobmartin/status/207281655130488832) the second link: "People doing BDD _through_ the UI are NOT doing BDD at all. They're doing MDD: Mess Driven Development."

Comment: Ryan, since I've seen BDD through the UI done very successfully, I'd say: it's hard, it requires particular expertise that not many devs have, the design of your BDD infrastructure and choice of automation framework is just as important as your ordinary code, and just because Uncle Bob hasn't done it successfully doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: Liz, it's exactly that which concerns me.  I believe you that it can be done, but as the [ThoughtWorks Radar](http://thoughtworks.fileburst.com/assets/thoughtworks-tech-radar-march-2012-us-color.pdf) recently posited, it has "encouraged doing the bulk of testing where the cost to run the tests is greatest."  I would like to see more discussion in the BDD community about the expertise and infrastructure required to do it successfully.  It's too easy to get it wrong.

Comment: I'll be talking about it at Agile 2012 in Dallas in August. I posted about the Page Paradigm here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10681801/363592 - might help

Comment: @Ryan, just read the radar and completely agree. The majority of companies I see doing BDD are writing way too many scenarios for boring stuff that the business will have no interest in. They're trying to use BDD as a regression mechanism instead of as an exploratory one. That's usually going to bite. I've only worked in 1 place where we had 100% scenario-based acceptance testing through the UI, and in retrospect, having time to do that should have been a red flag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to BDD myself, but I found the cuke4ninja site to help in this regard. What they suggest (my interpretation) is you have your step definitions which are high level and UI agnostic, that calls into a "workflow" class which groups the details like "click this button", "populate this field" into a method that captures the workflow under test, which calls into a "screen driver" class that handles the UI automation for that particular screen. That way all the UI automation code is abstracted away from the step definitions and are in a single location, and if the UI change, you just have to change the code in the "screen driver" instead of all multiple tests. [Here](http://cuke4ninja.com/chp_three_layers.html) is the relevant page where it is discussed.

Answer (score 1):

**What does the BDD is describing?**

In teams following a Behaviour Driven Development (BDD), the Acceptance Criteria (aka Rules) should describe "what the system does" instead of "how the system does it".

**So, where are the UI/UX details are captured in a team which is following BDD?**

In teams using BDD, The User Interface (UI) and User Experience (UX) (buttons, clicks, animations, etc) layer details should not be included as an Acceptance Criteria (aka Rules) in text format, under a ticket (e.g. issued with a Software Ticketing Tool such as JIRA, GitLab, etc). Instead they should be included within the design screens (wireframes, user journey, individual screens etc). For example, text notes may be embedded on the design screens with annotations, or just as comments next to the screens.